# Cost of Referencing a library for just one use

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I know this is a truly weak example, but my question is more for understanding better programming practices, so please bear with me for the example itself.

In working on a program, I have a situation where I have to replace multiple characters in a string with a single, different character.

For example, all the characters in `{" ", "-", "/", "*"}` must all be replaced with an underscore `"_"`. But this only happens once in the entire program and the result is stored in a variable.

So, I know I could do it using multiple `String.Replace()` statements in the following way:

```
string ChangedString1 = MyString.Replace(" ", "_").Replace("-", "_").Replace("/", "_").Replace("*", "_");
```

But I know I could also do it using a regular expression such as:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
   ...
string ChangedString2 = Regex.Replace(MyString, @"[\s-/*]", "_");
```

---

Now, my question isn't about which method is better, rather the question is how costly is it to include the `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` statement for only one use such as this?
And, perhaps `System.Text` isn't that expensive, **but what about adding in other references for just one small use**?

The question is if there is some kind of a industry preference regarding at what point is it better to write your own method rather than including a reference to a library just for one or two of its smaller functions. **OR** am I mis-understanding how references work and are they not that expensive in the first place?

Thanks for your help and I hope this question makes sense!

Comment: You're confusing the concept of [**Adding References**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx) with the concept of the [**using Directive**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx). These are completely different things, you really need to read about.

Comment: What is more important milliseconds in startup time or hours in development time?

Comment: @HighCore - You are right! - I got that from the answers posted now... I guess my question is more about when to decide to add a reference, then. But it seems there is no clear-cut answer to that one, huh? Rather a case-by-case basis...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

References to `.NET Framework` libraries aren't expensive relative to the rest of your program. You should solve the problem at hand the easiest way possible without wondering about that.

If you would need a *third party* reference and your user would need to have that installed or if it had a different license, that would be another can of worms, where I can see that thinking about coding a little function yourself makes sense.

Comment: Thanks, nvoigt! - That makes perfect sense! So I guess there is no standard regarding external libraries... More of a case-by-case basis??

Comment: @JohnBustos Exactly. The "cost" of using any inbuilt .NET functionality is basically zero, the "cost" of any third party reference has to be evaluated and weighted against the benefits for each.

Answer (score 8):

`using` statements are a purely compile-time feature that let you omit the namespace when referencing a class.
They have no effect at runtime.

Those classes are in mscorlib.dll, which you're referencing anyway.

Comment: Thanks!! - That makes sense! But, again, in this case I can understand that this won't make a difference, then, But what about actually referencing an external library just for one function?

Comment: For what it's worth, the `Regex` class is in `System.dll` which you are probably referencing already as well.

Answer (score 1):

The only real cost of adding a separate library is that of memory. This is obviously not much of an issue on modern day computers, unless of course you are working within a really tight memory footprint and using something like [the .NET Micro Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework).

Other answers describe the requirement of licences and distribution complexities etc... that also come from references.